# Perimeter of a quadrilateral and other shapes

Tags: python

So today in science class I thought of making a python script for basic perimeter of a quadrilateral. Later in future I want to expand into circle and other shape but I got stuck in error. Please help.

My code:

```
print ("This is a program to find the perimeter of a quadrilateral. Input the length and breath and get the desired perimeter")
len = input("What is the length?")
bre = input("What is the breath?")
length = len + len
breath = bre + bre
perimeter = length + breath
print ("The perimeter of the quadrilateral is :" + perimeter)
```

https://repl.it/xHG

And the output comes funky. If `l=2` and `b=1` then output comes as `2211`.

Also, how do you expand it into different shapes? I was thinking of using if and else options so `if choice = circle` then execute circle code `elif if choice = triangle` then execute triangle code. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Your `len` and `bre` variables are strings, you'll have to convert them to numbers, using for example `float(len)`. Please include your code in your question, instead of linking to external resources.

Comment: `input()` returns a `str` type. You need to convert it to an `int` first.

Comment: `input()` returns `int` type only if you work in `Python2.x`...

Comment: Finwood sir. I am extrelemy sorry. I am new to this website and didnt know about that. And Thank you a lot Andersson sir and Kamehameha sir. I solved it with your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert you input to an `int` or `float`.

```
len = float(input("What is the length?"))
```

In your code

```
len = input("What is the length?")
```

`len` is a string, and therefor when you perform `len + len` you are performing String [concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: Thank you sir. Very easy to understand. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember to convert data types

```
print ("This is a program to find the perimeter of a quadrilateral. Input the length and breath and get the desired perimeter")
len = input("What is the length?")
bre = input("What is the breath?")
len=int(len)
bre=int(bre)
length = len + len
breath = bre + bre
perimeter = length + breath
print ("The perimeter of the quadrilateral is :" + str(perimeter))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `input` returns a string (this is different in Python 2.x, which may be part of the confusion).

That means that `length = len + len` is actually performing string concatenation, ie. `'2' + '2' = '22'`.

Using either `int(input("..."))` or `float(input("..."))` will turn them into numbers. (note that both functions will create errors if the user puts in strings that can't be converted to numbers.

Comment: Thank you sir. Easy to understand. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @BakaOppai Glad it helped! Make sure to upvote answers that were helpful and accept the answer that you feel best resolved your issue.